# Is there a way to test micropython code with two microbits?

Tags: micropython, bbc-microbit

I have to make this code so two microbits can interact with each other.
But I can't test it since I only have one.
Is there a way to test this code through some online website/plugin/something?
Code:
https://pastebin.com/N0FirrsD (This code will receive and act accordingly)

```
from microbit import *
import radio

#Pin 0 is the left motor
#Pin 1 is the right motor
#Pin 3 is a buzzer

Starten = false

while Starten == false:
    if button_a.is_pressed():
        Starten = true
    else:
        microbit.display.scroll('Druk op A')
        
radio.on()
radio.config(channel=56)
radio.config(power=7)

while Starten == true:
    Commando = radio.receive()
    
    if Commando == "vooruit":
        pin0.write_digital(1)
        pin1.write_digital(1)
        
    if Commando == "remmen":
        pin0.write_digital(0)
        pin1.write_digital(0)
        
    if Commando == "links":
        pin0.write_digital(0)
        pin1.write_digital(1)
    
    if Commando == "rechts":
        pin0.write_digital(1)
        pin1.write_digital(0)
        
    if Commando == "toeter":
        pin3.write_digital(1)
        sleep(2000)
        pin3.write_digital(0)
        
    if button_b.is_pressed():
        Starten = false:
```

https://pastebin.com/SPbLtWGr (This code will send commands)

```
from microbit import *
import radio


Starten = false

while Starten == false:
    if button_a.is_pressed():
        Starten = true
    else:
        microbit.display.scroll('Druk op A')
        
radio.on()
radio.config(channel=56)
radio.config(power=7)

while Starten == true:
    if accelerometer.is_gesture("up"):
        radio.send("vooruit")
        
    if accelerometer.is_gesture("down"):
        radio.send("remmen)
        
    if accelerometer.is_gesture("left"):
        radio.send("links")
        
    if accelerometer.is_gesture("right"):
        radio.send("rechts)
        
    if button_a.is_pressed():
        radio.send("toeter)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to write some stub modules (`microbit`, `radio`, etc) that will let you test your code under regular Python. This will help flush out basic syntax errors (e.g., several of your print statements are missing a closing quote).

You can use files or FIFOs to simulate the radio and GPIO features.